# Python project structure, issue with imports

Tags: python, python-3.x

My project structure so far:

```
Project/
|-- crypto/
|   |-- one.py
|   |   two.py
|-- utils/
|   |-- util1.py
|   |   util2.py
....
```

Within the files, I have been importing like this:

```
# within one.py
from utils.util1 import xy
```

Now that I want to build a webservice that uses most of these python scripts, I thought of moving them into a separate folder:

```
Project/
|-- service.py
|-- lib/
|    |-- crypto/
|    |   |-- one.py
|    |   |   two.py
|    |-- utils/
|    |   |-- util1.py
|    |   |   util2.py
|    ....
```

My problem is, that now, I would have to modify all import statements in every single file to something like this:

```
from lib.utils.util1 import xy
```

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the `lib` folder to PYTHONPATH environment variable then your modules will be available without any changes in source files.
The format is the same as the shell’s PATH.

More information: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH

Comment: But mind the fact, that you´ve got to do this on every system where you want to use this. So if you share it on github or migrate it to newer system then don´t forget to do this and to document this for others.

Comment: It's always better to provide .sh or .cmd script for launching non trivial environments like this.